# How can i Transpose Table or Create Pivote table

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

I have the following information i will like to create a Pivot Table Customer name and Sum the amount.

```
Customer ID   Customer Bill Name  Item ID  Transaction Date  Amount ...
Cust 1          Customer 1         123       '2017-03-03'     2
Cust 1          Customer 1         123       '2017-02-03'     3
Cust 3          Customer 3         235       '2017-01-03'     4
Cust 3          Customer 3         235       '2017-01-03'     4
```

i want to accomplish

```
Customer ID   Customer Bill Name  Item ID  JAN   FEB  MARCH ...
Cust 1          Customer 1         123      2     3    0
Cust 3          Customer 3         235      8     0    0
```

I have the following code to generate the records from the table

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerID, Customers.Customer_Bill_Name, Customers.WhichShipVia, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT LineItem.ItemID) AS ItemIDgroup, JrnlHdr.INV_POSOOrderNumber, JrnlHdr.CustomerInvoiceNo, JrnlHdr.Comment2, JrnlHdr.ShipByDate, JrnlHdr.GoodThruDate, JrnlHdr.CustomerSONo, JrnlHdr.Reference, JrnlHdr.TransactionDate, JrnlRow.DistNumber, JrnlRow.Quantity, LineItem.ItemID, LineItem.SalesDescription, LineItem.PartNumber, LineItem.Category, LineItem.ItemClass, LineItem.ItemDescription 
FROM   Customers
INNER JOIN JrnlHdr
ON Customers.CustomerRecordNumber = JrnlHdr.CustVendId
INNER JOIN JrnlRow
ON JrnlHdr.PostOrder = JrnlRow.PostOrder

INNER JOIN LineItem 
ON JrnlRow.ItemRecordNumber = LineItem.ItemRecordNumber

WHERE  JrnlHdr.TransactionDate>='2016-01-01' AND JrnlHdr.JrnlKey_Journal = 3 AND JrnlHdr.PostOrder = JrnlRow.PostOrder  AND JrnlHdr.CustVendId = Customers.CustomerRecordNumber AND JrnlRow.ItemRecordNumber = LineItem.ItemRecordNumber GROUP BY LineItem.ItemID
```

Comment: Where do the values '2016-01-01' and 3 come from?

Comment: And if this is sql-server then remove the mysql tag

Comment: For MySQL, this can help you build the pivot code:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot

Comment: @Strawberry its from sage database PSQL then converted to MYSQL so that data comes from Mysql and works fine

Comment: Er, I mean in the query itself.

Comment: @Strawberry that i was just testing to filter and retrieve 2016 data and  2017, the 3 or JrnlHdr.JrnlKey_Journal = 3 means sales invoice